# jQuery what is the correct way to fix this `closure`

Tags: jquery, foreach

I am looping an array, but I am getting multiple instance of array length. is there any in-

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'name1',
  value: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}, {
  name: 'name3',
  value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}];

var makeDropDown = function() {
  var newhtml = function(value) {
    var name = $('<td/>', {
      text: value.name
    });
    var build = $('<tr/>').append(name).append($('<td/>'));
    $("tbody").append(build);
  }

  if (!array.length) 
    return;

  $.each(array, function(index, value) {
    newhtml(value); //my try to avoid clousure not works!
  })
}

makeDropDown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <theader>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </theader>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfooter></tfooter>
</table>
```

build way to avoid this in jQuery?

Comment: issue in your `newHtml` function

Comment: what is that? can you figure out please?

Comment: Pass the index  as argument into `newhtml(value);`. So it becomes ` newhtml(index);`

Comment: @Abolarinstephen - i can pass, but what about the conditional out put here?

Comment: your `tbody` appended twice in code. Thats y issue occures.

Comment: Yes, I accept. I am looking for a way to avoid it.

Comment: @3gwebtrain please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no `theader` and `tfooter` it must be `thead` and `tfoot`

```js
var array = [{
  name: 'name1',
  value: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}, {
  name: 'name2',
  value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}, {
  name: 'name3',
  value: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}];

var makeDropDown = function() {
  var newhtml = function(value) {
    var name = $('<td/>', {
      text: value.name
    });
    var build = $('<tr/>').append(name).append($('<td/>'));
    //console.log(build);
    $("tbody").append(build);
    
  }

  if (!array.length) 
    return;

  $.each(array, function(index, value1) {
    newhtml(value1); //my try to avoid clousure not works!
  })
}

makeDropDown();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working as expected, because the browser "fixes" your markup and adds another `TBODY` element.

Either fix the markup, or make the tbody identifiable:

```
<tbody id="root"></tbody>
```

and change the newhtml to:

```
...
$("tbody#root").append(build);
```

Also, do not **avoid** [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). They be a ***good thing*** :)

Comment: getting same result, can you update with working example?